# Time (hour/minute/am or pm) variables in SPSS

Tags: time, spss, date-arithmetic

I am trying to calculate the length of time that a person sleeps. My dataset includes the following variables: `SleepHour`, `SleepMinute`, `SleepAM_PM`, `WakeHour`, `WakeMinute`, and `WakeAM_PM`. The hour variable ranges from 1-12, the minute variable ranges from 0-59, and the AM/PM variable is binary (1 = AM; 2 = PM).

I tried the following code and it was close but it didn't account for the fact that minutes are measured on a 60-point scale, so a person who sleeps at 11:00pm and wakes at 6:30am was listed as getting 7.70 hours of sleep, although it should be 7.30.

```
* Calculate time spent asleep with decimal places.
COMPUTE SleepMilitaryTime = 0.
COMPUTE WakeMilitaryTime = 0.
COMPUTE SleepDuration = 0.

* Convert sleep time to military time.
IF (SleepAM_PM = "PM" & SleepHour < 12) SleepMilitaryTime = (SleepHour + 12) * 100 + SleepMinute.
IF (SleepAM_PM = "AM" & SleepHour = 12) SleepMilitaryTime = SleepMinute.
IF (SleepAM_PM = "AM" & SleepHour < 12) SleepMilitaryTime = SleepHour * 100 + SleepMinute.

* Convert wake time to military time.
IF (WakeAM_PM = "PM" & WakeHour < 12) WakeMilitaryTime = (WakeHour + 12) * 100 + WakeMinute.
IF (WakeAM_PM = "AM" & WakeHour = 12) WakeMilitaryTime = WakeMinute.
IF (WakeAM_PM = "AM" & WakeHour < 12) WakeMilitaryTime = WakeHour * 100 + WakeMinute.

* Calculate sleep duration with decimal places.
IF (WakeMilitaryTime >= SleepMilitaryTime) SleepDuration = (WakeMilitaryTime - SleepMilitaryTime) / 100.
IF (WakeMilitaryTime < SleepMilitaryTime) SleepDuration = ((2400 + WakeMilitaryTime) - SleepMilitaryTime) / 100.

EXECUTE.
```

I also tried using the SPSS Date and Time Wizard, but I think that works only when the hours are in 24-hour time and these are not.

If you know how to solve this problem, I would be very grateful!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention having a date, so the following code covers for it by adding 24 to the waking time if needed, before calculating the total sleep time":

```
* first calculate one number for sleep and for wake time.
recode SleepHour WakeHour (12=0).
compute slp = SleepHour + (SleepMinute/60) + 12*(SleepAM_PM=2).
compute wak = WakeHour + (WakeMinute/60) + 12*(WakeAM_PM=2).
    
* now since we don't have the date we assume that since wake  
  time is later than sleep time, it is either bigger than 
  sleep time, or smaller - in the next day.
if wak < slp wak = wak + 24.

* now we're ready to calculate total sleep time in hours.
compute totalSleepTime = wak - slp.
execute.
```

Comment: Hmm that didn't work for me, but I appreciate your reply! It just produced a blank variable.

Comment: Just run `execute.` at the end of the process. I'll add it in the answer.